# How to fix "No JPEG data found in image"

Tags: caffe, mpeg

I'm using C3D-v1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, compiled with opencv 2.4. I completed the examples provided, extracting feature from video and frames, with no error occurred. But when I tried to extract feature from my own video(mpeg4, H.264) using the default settings, it kept telling me "[mjpeg @ 0xafe5920] No JPEG data found in image".

I tried to install ffmpeg, ubuntu-restricted-extras and vlc, but no luck.

The [ouput of the terminal](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AndersonZhangyq/files/master/terminal-output.txt?token=ATmS7NYsPqGc00ZGdjOZ9OqCckuSkUVoks5cNrBdwA%3D%3D) is uploaded.

What is the possible cause of this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: is it possible your video file is corrupted?

Comment: @Shai I could play that video normally, so I think the video file is ok.

Comment: Just tried solving this for vlc, and through sheer experimentation I found that the error only appears when at 1080p@60hz resolution, and goes away when set to 720p or even 1080p@30hz

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986459/low-fps-choppy-video-no-sound-no-jpeg-data-found-in-image-when-using-webca/65986591#65986591

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found that this is a ffmpeg related problem. The error message "No JPEG data found in image" can be found in the source code of ffmpeg/libavcodec/mjpegdec.c.

Since I successfully extracted feature without any error in ubuntu 18.04, I checked the build information of opencv and found that the version of libavcodec was different. (57.107.100 in ubuntu 18.04, 56.60.100 in ubuntu 16.04).Manually compile ffmpeg and use new version of libavcodec solved my problem.

Comment: would you mind sharing a couple resources you followed to change the libavcodec version?